# Passing data between Views and Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Wanted to see if somebody can provide some suggestions/pointers on how to address this issue I am currently facing
.
Scenario is like…

1. I have a Page say A where search is performed and data is displayed.
2. On Page A there is an ActionLink which passes an ID of the selected record to the page B.
3. Before redirecting to page B, I need to store/preserve form data of Page A (I do not want to use session or hidden filed as data is critical).
4. Once user is done working on Page B, I need to save changes on Page B and redirect back to Page A.
5. Here Page A should make a Post request based on preserver form data in step 3. Purpose is to display back searched data that was there before redirecting to Page B.

Something like..

```
View A
    // Search textboxes here
    // Search data list here with ActionLink column

View B
   // more controls here
   // Submit button - saves changes on this page. 
   // after submit button processing need to go back to View A 
   // and display the same Search data List based on Seach textboxes values 
   // those were entered by user before coming to this View B. 
   // Ques: Not sure how to persist data from View A between calls to View B and then View B to View A.
```

Does anybody has any better approach to achieve this?

For now the solution I have is...

1. Make an ajax POST request on ActionLink click and save the
   formcollection in cache using controller.
2. Make default ActionLink GET request passing ID and in controller
   return View B.
3. On View B, on submit do ajax POST request to save data on Page B and
   return data from cache in ajax success function.
4. Make another ajax POST request using data retruned in above ajax
   success to display View A.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very difficult to understand what is it exactly that you are trying to achieve here without having the real context. However, from what you are saying it seems like a javascript single page application might be more suitable here rather than leaving rendering to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on full page refreshes then you need to use Session. You didn't give a reason as to why you don't want to use it, but Cache object is totally inappropriate for this purpose as it can be cleared out if the server needs to regain some memory, as well it is shared between users. Session is specifically built for the purpose you're describing - preserving data between full page refreshes.

Alternatively I would look into building your site as a Single Page Application, aka, you don't do full page refreshes between navigation, and can store data in a javascript object on the client. Due to the fact you put a lot of emphasis that the data is critical, the Session might be safer though as your javascript objects will get cleared out if the user accidentally navigates away from the page, where is a server based session object will preserve it for the duration of the session lifecycle.

You can also store the data in a cookie/local storage object (html5), but this is probably overkill for what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for useful details on storing the data between Views. I was also wondring if you have some thoughts on the approach I have taken to achieve this using multiple ajax calls at one click (ActinLink on View A, Submuit button on View B). Any better approach available?

Comment: What I would recommend is instead of doing Html.ActionLink on page A, do a Ajax.ActionLink and load the new data into an overlapping HTML element, that way your data is still preserved "in the background of the page". You can make your page B open as a modal popup, do the work, and after it's complete close the overlapping modal popup revealing page A underneath. This will have the benefit of having the nicest "UI" experience since it won't do a full page refresh. Your page B should also use Ajax.Form instead of Html.Form to ensure that it doesn't do a full page refresh

Comment: I cannot use modal popup as Page B has lots of data and has its own modal popups. Currently I am stuck with where I am done with button submit process but I cannot call Post method of View A. (post because I need to pass search textboxes data and perform search).